# Subquery in MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to create an SQL statement that will get the following information:
ISBN, Quantity, OrderTotal, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, and StreetAddress from multiple tables.

Here are the two queries i have so far that give me the information i need:

**CustomerInfo**

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.PhoneNumber, a.StreetAddress
FROM Customers AS c, Address AS a
WHERE c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID;
```

**OrderInfo**

```
SELECT o.CustomerID, o.OrderTotal, i.ISBN, i.Quantity
FROM Orders AS o, OrderItems as i
WHERE o.OrderID = i.OrderID;
```

**CombinedQuery**                   *This doesn't work!!!*

```
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.PhoneNumber, c.StreetAddress, o.OrderTotal, o.ISBN, o.Quantity
FROM CustomerInfo as c, OrderInfo as o
WHERE c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID;
```

How do i join the first two queries into one query that will provide the same information that the third query *should* provide?

Comment: And what exactly "doesn't work" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `CustomerId` field in `OrderInfo`.  You need all three tables

```
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.PhoneNumber, c.StreetAddress,
       oi.OrderTotal, oi.ISBN, oi.Quantity
FROM (Customers as c INNER JOIN
      Orders AS o
      ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
     ) INNER JOIN
     OrderItems as oi
     ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID;
```

You also need to learn proper `join` syntax with an `on` clause.  Implicit joins in the `where` clause are outdated, less expressive, and more prone to error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.PhoneNumber, 
a.StreetAddress, 
o.CustomerID, o.OrderTotal, 
i.ISBN, i.Quantity
FROM Customers AS c, Address AS a, Orders AS o, OrderItems as i
WHERE o.OrderID = i.OrderID;
AND c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
AND c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID;
```

Try that as one big query instead of doing two and then combining them. This will join together all four of your tables.